# Plots not showing up on HTML file after running in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

When I generate plot in Rmarkdown, it shows up under Plots in Rstudio but does not include it when I knit it. How can I include the plot in the markdown?

I also have "Create a standalone HTML document" checked and similarly plots don't show up in that standalone HTML document.

e.g. I run this code in Rmarkdown file but plot does not stay in the knitted document.

```
boxplot(bwt ~ smoke, data=birthwt,
        xlab = "drivetrain (0 = don't smoke, 1 = smoke)",
        ylab = "birth wt. in g",
        main = "birth weight vs smoking status",
        pch = 20,
        cex = 2,
        col = "darkslategray",
        border = "goldenrod3")
```

Please advise.

Comment: The code for the plot is as it is and I just have text above and below the code snippet. After I get the plot on the doc, I will enclose the code in ``` ``` to make it into a block.

Comment: I'm thinking one option is to save the plot from Plots separately and try to import  it back into Rmarkdown?

Comment: If you are wrapping it with `r` code chunk, it should work

Comment: Can you explain what the initial r code chunk does or how it works? ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Comment: That is just a template I had in one of my previous rmd files.  I think it is not needed for this to work here.  It is just a global declaration to set the `echo = TRUE` for all chunks if not overridden by `echo = FALSE` in each chunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does work in the following small snippet of `RMD`

````
---
title: "testing"
author: "akrun"
date: "10/05/2021"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r}
library(MASS)
data(birthwt)
boxplot(bwt ~ smoke, data=birthwt,
        xlab = "drivetrain (0 = don't smoke, 1 = smoke)",
        ylab = "birth wt. in g",
        main = "birth weight vs smoking status",
        pch = 20,
        cex = 2,
        col = "darkslategray",
        border = "goldenrod3")

```
````

-output

[image]